# File reader Sync

Tags: reactjs, filereader

I have the following javascript code which is trying to upload a file to a repository but I need to pass it as a buffer first. The problem is my "getBatchFileBuffer" function is somehow continuing without waiting for it to resolve which make the "UploadFiles" to only get a promise and not the real object. TIA

```
const getBatchFileBuffer = file => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
      file[0].fileBuffer = e.target.result;
      resolve(file);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file[0].fileObject);
  });
};

getBatchFileBuffer(self.state.tempAttachment).then(function(
            tempAttachment
          ) {
            self.setState({ tempAttachment });
            UploadFiles(
              self.state.AppMainObject.ID,
              getBatchFileBuffer(self.state.tempAttachment)
            ).then(function(UploadFilesFileURL) {
              console.log(UploadFilesFileURL);
            });
          });
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it sure that the "getBatchFileBuffer" function is 100% done

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the solution, I was calling the "getBatchFileBuffer" twice. That was my mistake